# in Genitive Singular for Masculine and Neutral nouns, it's added "-s" or "-es"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, genitive

[image]

In Singular Genitiv for the neutral noun "Das Buch" they wrote in Duden "des Buches, Buchs", is there a rule to choose if we must add "-s" or "-es" to the noun, or something else?!!

Comment: @RegDwight: IMHO the linked question addresses the point what to do when you can use both _-es_ and _-s_ in the genitive form. I understand this one however as also asking for a guide when both and when only one ending is possible (especially in the heading) - so for me this is not a 100% duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

The answer, as often with languages, is: *It depends.* The question itself however needs to be tackled in two steps:

## Determine allowed Suffixes

At first you need to make sure which *genitive singular* suffixes are actually allowed for a given word. There are three types of nouns in the German language when it comes to this:

- *-es* only, clearly marking the case suffix:

  - **all nouns ending with *s*, *ß*, *x* or *z***, e.g. *des Glases*, *des Straußes*, *des Reflexes*, *des Sturzes*
- *-s* only, for more melodic intonation of the word (*-es* would sound wrong) or alignment with the plural:

  - **many nouns ending with an unstressed syllable**, e.g. *des Abends*, *des Reichtums*
  - **all nouns ending with an unstressed *-e*, *-el*, *-er*, *-en*, *-chen*, *-lein* and *ling***, e.g. *des Vogels*, *des Lehrlings*, *des Bodens*
  - **most loan words**, especially those with plural-*s*, e.g. *des Textils*, *des Generals*, *des Hotels*
- *-s* or *-es*:

  - **all others**

The [inflection class](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Flexionsklasse&language=0&project=1) of a word is also an indicator, whether only one option is allowed.

**[canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/Texte/s-und-es-Gen.html)** gives a more detailled overview with many more examples.

## Choosing *-s* or *-es* if both are allowed

For a word where both endings are allowed *-es* is indeed considered more poetic as stated by [accolade](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9254/in-genitive-singular-for-masculine-and-neutral-nouns-its-added-s-or-es/9256#9256), but could also be interpreted as outdated. The [Duden](https://web.archive.org/web/20190726113514/https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Genitiv-auf-s-oder-es) says that *-es* is preferred in constellations where the genetive is prefixed (e.g. *des Tages Hitze*) or within compounds with interfix-*s* (*des Geschäftsfreundes*).

Answer (score 0):

Folgendes stellt keine feste Regel dar, aber ich würde sagen, *-es* ist lyrischer/ (gehobener(?));
*-s* ist der Normalfall.