# Genitiv: Elementes vs. Elements

Tags: meaning, word-choice, genitive, suffix

Gibt es irgendeinen semantischen oder stilistischen Unterschied zwischen den zwei Genitivformen von "Element"? Wenn ja, welchen?

Insbesondere interessiert mich der wissenschaftliche Kontext, wie z.B. in "Unabhängig von der Wahl des Element(e)s der Menge X gilt ..." in einem Mathematik-Buch.

Comment: [Rules for when -s or -es are mandatory in the genitive](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46084/rules-for-when-s-or-es-are-mandatory-in-the-genitive) is related

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt keinen semantischen Unterschied. Er ist rein stilistisch: Bei mehrsilbigen Nomen kann das (e) weggelassen werden.
Spezialfälle sind Wörter mit Endung auf ss, tz etc.

Comment: Natürlich ist das eine Frage des Stils. Wie definierst du denn, was Stil ist?

Comment: stell dir vor einen Text voller Genitive mit -es  statt der Kurzform (e)s ... was für ein grässlicher Stil :)

Comment: Bitte verweise nicht auf Kommentare, sie sind nicht dazu gedacht, dauerhaft zu sein.

Comment: Ich empfinde "des Elementes" als gehobener als "des Elements". Eine Mathematikprofessorin würde also vielleicht in einem Buch "Elementes" schreiben, aber in der Vorlesung "Elements" sagen.

Comment: genau, so würde ich es auch machen.